# Animated film or maybe anime? from 1980 (probably)

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I've glimpsed a part of it in my childhood, and it still bugs be that I cannot find what it was. Here's what I remember, only some pictures, no plot:

Some planet, most likely Earth. There are large robots, rather rounded-looking, with one big 'eye' in the head. There is some resistance, whose fighters are trying to take those robots down.
When some of those do go down, they emit a beam of light from that 'eye', which goes all the way into space, as a means to summon something like their mothership.

At some point this mothership does arrive. The ground melts where it touches it.

Near the end (?), someone fires a rifle-looking weapon, but from which a projectile comes, It hits the ground, the ground also starts melting, and emits several same projectiles the that point, so they multiply, and then a view form space is shown, where the whole planet is being covered in lava (?)

Comment: Until the beam summoning a mothership, I thought this was *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Winds.*  There were also similar robots in *Castle in the Sky* -- both from Studio Ghibli -- but neither one summoned a mothership.